# Overriding generic methods with non-generic implementations

Tags: java, generics

I'm experimenting with generics in Java, and thought of this example.

If I have `ClassA<T>`, I can override it with a subclass that references a concrete class, such as `ClassB extends ClassA<String>`, then anywhere ClassA uses T, ClassB can use a String.

Now, ignoring the previous `ClassA` and `ClassB`, if I have an abstract `ClassA`, which has a generic method:

```
public <T> void doSomething(T data);
```

Is there any way I can have a `ClassB` that overrides it with a concrete class, similar to the previous example? I've come up with something that works, which is to parameterize both the class and the method, but I'm wondering if there's another way.

```
class ClassA<T> {
    public void doSomething(T data) {};
}
```

The reason I don't want to put the parameter in the class is because it's only one method that does anything with that type, and some subclasses may not even want to do anything in that method, so I shouldn't need to put a parameter in the class if it's not going to use it.

**NOTE**: All of the subclasses of `ClassA` are anonymous classes, so that adds to the fun.

Comment: See the answer from @wowest from a similar question

[Overriding Generic Methods in Java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632033/overriding-java-generic-methods

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), this:

```
public <T> void doSomething(T data);
```

Really means this:

```
public void doSomething(Object data);
```

So no, there isn't a way to override with a more restrictive parameter type.

Also in this code:

```
class ClassA<T> {
    public <T> void doSomething(T data) {};
}
```

The type parameter in your class name and the type parameter in the method are actually different parameters. It's like declaring a local variable of the same name as a variable in a higher scope. You can call `doSomething(123)` on an instance of `ClassA<String>` because the second `T` is local to the method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is such a weird feature in Java. What is the point of restricting the type at the class level, if all the method type does is restrict the user to Object? It does not make sense to me at any rate. If I want a method to be Generic, what you are saying is that <T> is of no use...unless the <T> declared at class level.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the the answer is no.  If you define a method with a generic parameter, then its signature contains a the generic and any "overrides" would have to match the signature (contain a generic).

Anyhow, this really is a poor use of generics, as what you've written is semantically the same as

```
public void doSomething(Object data) {}
```

The generic bit doesn't buy you much unless is it being used to indicate what the return value would be, as in:

```
public <T> T doSomething(T data) {}
```

But why bother?  Is there really an issue calling doSomething() generically?

Comment: Man, I hate it when somebody posts effectively the same answer while I'm being interrupted.