# How to extends from generic type and override method parameter type with subclass

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with generic class hierarchy and method override. I tried to do something like below:

```
public class Configuration<S> {
  private List<S> elements;

  <T extends Configuration<S>> Configuration<S> merge(T anotherConfig) {
    return anotherConfig;
  }
}
```

and the subclass looks like:

```
public class ExtendedConfiguration extends Configuration<String> {

  @Override
  ExtendedConfiguration merge(ExtendedConfiguration anotherConfig) {
    return anotherConfig;
  }
}
```

However, subclass does not compile and I have no clue how to declare method in Configuration class so I can override it in subclass with subclass type as parameter. I want to avoid explicit casting.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65465634/an-object-can-hold-an-array-of-its-own-objects-but-how-does-this-work-together/65465786). You need to add another generic parameter to the _class_, and the method should not be generic.

Comment: The problem is Configuration class already has a type argument S

Comment: That's not a problem. Just add another type argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html): `merge` in `Configuration` becomes:

```java
Configuration merge(Configuration anotherConfig) {
    return anotherConfig;
}
```

For `ExtendedConfiguration` to override `merge`, it must have `Configuration` as method param type. So, below `ExtendedConfiguration` is fine:

```java
class ExtendedConfiguration extends Configuration<String> {

    @Override
    Configuration<String> merge(Configuration anotherConfig) {
        return anotherConfig;
    }
}
```

`@Override` instructs the compiler to check if the method is being inherited.

With the declaration in question:

```java
public class ExtendedConfiguration extends Configuration<String> {

  @Override
  ExtendedConfiguration merge(ExtendedConfiguration anotherConfig) {
    return anotherConfig;
  }
}
```

it's overloading instead. If you remove `@Override`, it will compile fine.

---

To achieve your requirement, you can use [recursive generics](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-generics-java-%E2%80%93-0):

The updated declarations may look like:

**Configuration**

```java
class Configuration<T extends Configuration<T, S>, S> {
    private List<S> elements;

    Configuration<T, S> merge(T anotherConfig) {
        return anotherConfig;
    }
}
```

**ExtendedConfiguration**

```java
class ExtendedConfiguration extends Configuration<ExtendedConfiguration, String> {

    @Override
    ExtendedConfiguration merge(ExtendedConfiguration anotherConfig) {
        return anotherConfig;
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049420/javahow-to-override-this-generic-method) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357824/overriding-generic-methods-with-non-generic-implementations).